# Не получается подключится к моему айфон и запустить приложение на нем

Tags: swift, xcode

на этом скрине я пытаюсь, подключить приложение к моему устройству. Но я думаю, что проблема в сертификате. Так как, он не отображается в VPN&Device Managment. Как удалить сертификат?

[image: 1]

Comment: Похоже что вы наклепали слишком много Bundle ID за короткое время. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701805